# Why does Python behave differently for the same function such as 'sum' or 'and'?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**

- Scenario 1: `sum`

**
I found that when working on 2d arrays in numpy, I realised that summing up has different options - i.e., Python built-in method `sum` provides summation along the axes only, whereas the numpy `sum` provides summation on the total 2d array (matrix).

**

- Scenario 2: `and` versus `&`

**

I noticed that logical and (`and`) bitwise and (`&`) both work on the same data element but produce different results. In fact, Logical and  `and` does not work within `series` of `dataframe` whereas bitwise and `&` works just fine.

Why does this happen ? Can anybody provide insights based on the language's history, design, purpose, etc so one can understand better ?

Regards
Ssp

Comment: `and` just takes the truthiness of the left operand. If that truthiness is `False` it "returns" te first operand, otherwise it returns the right operand. But not all objects have truthiness.

Comment: Regarding `sum`, that function simply sums up the elements from the given argument. An array iterates by yield its rows one at a time, so `sum(a)` is adding rows, not elements of the array. It's basically a design tradeoff: a type can only have one kind of iterator, and it was probably deemed more useful or logical for an array iterator to yield rows, rather than individual elements. An additional `sum` *method* is free to be defined however is useful.

Comment: Thanks. Why not provide these via answers so you guys get credit for it ?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` operates within Python, and gets all its special behavior from `ndarray` class methods and module functions.  It does not alter Python syntax.

Python `sum` treats its input as an iterable; it's easy to understand with a 1d array, which is just like operating on a list.  But on a 2d array, it's harder to understand:

```
In [52]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                         
In [53]: sum(x)                                                                 
Out[53]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])    # what's this doing?
In [54]: x.sum()        # or np.sum(x)                                                            
Out[54]: 66
In [55]: x.sum(axis=0)                                                          
Out[55]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])    # sum down rows, one per column
In [56]: x.sum(axis=1)                                                          
Out[56]: array([ 6, 22, 38])        # sum across columns, one per row
```

Python `and` is a short circuiting operator.  Like an `if` statement, its use with numpy arrays is likely to produce an `ambiguity` error.  Comparisons of arrays produces boolean arrays.  Boolean arrays cannot be used in Python contexts that require a scalar boolean value.

Operators like `+`,`*`,`&` has class specific meanings/methods. `[1,2,3]*3` is different from `np.array([1,2,3])*3`.  `"a"+"string"` is different from `np.arange(3)+3`.